# Can I use Keras or a similar CNN tool on a paired image and coordinate?

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras

I am trying to train a classifier to separate images taken by a particle physics detector into two classes. For each image, I also have a coordinate (x,y,z) describing where the particle interaction took place. That coordinate is very useful is understanding these images by eye, but doesn't have an obvious translation to weighting image pixels.

I've been trying some basic machine learning techniques in scikit-learn, feeding in data points with 103 features: the three axes of the coordinates, and the 10x10 pixels of the image. Those basic techniques aren't cutting it, unfortunately, so I thought I'd try to take advantage of the properties of convolutional neural networks. Since I've never tried that before, Keras seemed like an easy way to get started.

Looking at Keras, I see that I ought to provide an input shape. I could presumably use a input shape of (103), but if I understand CNN correctly, I'd lose all the advantages of CNN for images. Intuitively, what I want the input shape to be is (3)+(10,10). Is that a sensible concept in the world of CNN? Can it be done in Keras?

Comment: how big are your images?  10 by 10?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Merge layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#merge). In essence this allows you to use two independent inputs, maybe give them a few different processing layers and them combine them for the rest of the model.

With this you could, for example, do several convolutional layers to process the image and then simply merge it with the coordinate inputs.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I'm looking for. Do you know any real-world problems that are sometimes solved with merge layers? That can help me figure out if I understand the limitations and applications of the merge layer.

Comment: I'd expect most problems where you have multiple processing paths or multiple input modalities/sources will use that. If you are looking for a concrete usage example (other than tutorials and the likes) I just stumbled upon another question that uses this layer and might give you some inspiration - http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/multi-scale-cnn-network-python